# Django Celery Periodic Task ignoring contrab

Tags: django, django-celery

After an update it appears celery has stopped to work like it should. 
I have periodic tasks per day and from 6-22.
All of the tasks running from 6-22 run every 5 minutes for no reason.

I changed the task from running every hour to running from 6-22. The every hour function wasn't working either.

I tried: 
minute=0 hour=6-22, minute=0, hour='*/3,8-17' and completely written like below.
The last one i copied from the docs because i thought maybe this would work.

```
@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute=0, hour='6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22')),
    queue='feed',
    name="feed_update",
    ignore_result=True
)
def feed_update():
    """
    checks for feed updates
    """
    feed_update_for_all_users()
    logger.info("Feed Update complete")
```

settings.py

```
#CELERY STUFF
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('reviews.tasks',)
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 7776000} 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
```

According to the Docs these are all valid contrab vars. Why isn't it working properly?

Comment: Does it work if you use only one hour like `hour=6'`?

Comment: Are you sure your celery-beat's running ? The task configuration is alright and should work.

Comment: When you update the task code or crontab parameters, you should restart celery beat. Did you try it?

Comment: restarted beat quite a few times, deleted the celery beat schedule file. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev if i use crontab(minute=0, hour=0) it appears to work.

Comment: Why there is braces in `run_every=(crontab(minute=0, hour='6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22'))` shouldn't it be just `run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour='6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22')`?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev No change, maybe a settings problem?

Comment: @SpiXel what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through every Bug Report in Celery.

Celery doesn't accept any other timestamp!!!

Using CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False, pretty much wrecks the Programm.

Once you enable it, the problem will be solved. 
However if you have any eta functions you have to adjust the time before sending it to celery and of course if you have exact timeframes adjust these as well.